# How to remove failed retrial jobs using BullMQ?

Tags: node.js, typescript, bullmq

I use BullMQ to run jobs on the background. I have defined main job using retry strategy. I want to make sure that when main job fails and when retrying this job fails it removes retried failed jobs automatically. As I calculate error threshold and also do some other operations I need to make sure that failed jobs are the only main jobs upon retrieving them.

This is my current retry strategy:

```
{
  attempts: 10,
  backoff: {
    type: "exponential",
    delay: 1000,
  },
};
```

I have looked thorugh the documentation and could not find what kind of configuration or setup would do this.

Answer (score 0):

BullMQ doesn't create new jobs on retries, but rather runs the same job again.
The job will have the same id.
So you can be sure that failed jobs are the only main jobs upon retrieving them.